# How to deny int variable without explicit type annotation in Rust?

Tags: rust

I often use integer type without type annotation:

```rust
let mut counter = 0
```

If there is no constraint, rustc will infer `x` is a `i32`. ([rfcs/0212-restore-int-fallback.md at master · rust-lang/rfcs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0212-restore-int-fallback.md)).

Sometimes it causes a problem: overflowing.

```rust
for _ in 0..1_000_000_000_000usize {
    counter += 1; # overflow!
    ...
}
```

So I want to tell rustc to deny integer variable without explicit type annotation:

```
let mut counter = 0; # Deny
let mut counter: u64 = 0; # OK, because `counter` is explicitly annotated with `u64`
```

How to do this?

Comment: If what you want is some kind of [compiler lint](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rustc/lints/index.html) to deny integer literals without explicit types, I believe this is not currently possible. However, I'm pretty sure this could be implemented if you submit an issue against the rust repository.

Comment: Lazy type inference of integer literals is a Rust feature not a bug. It's very unlikely this would ever become an official compiler lint. However, it could possibly be implemented as an optional lint in [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) so I would try that first.

Comment: @pretzelhammer Note that the OP has nothing against lazy type inference of integer literals - see the final snippet. The OP would like a lint that disables the _fallback_ to `i32` that is just that, a fallback, and completely orthogonal to inference.

Comment: I've opened an issue to Clippy's repo: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/6634

Comment: There is a simpler way, than waiting around on issues to be implemented, and that is just to include your types where needed.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop Sure, any warning or lint can be replaced by simply not making the mistake in the first place! The OP does want to include the types, and further asks about a lint to warn in places where he forgets to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new lint [`default_numeric_fallback`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#default_numeric_fallback):

```rust
#[warn(clippy::default_numeric_fallback)]

pub fn is_yelled(s: &str) -> bool {
    let (n_upper, n_lower) = s.chars().fold((0, 0), |(n_upper, n_lower), c| {
        if c.is_uppercase() {
            (n_upper + 1, n_lower)
        } else if c.is_lowercase() {
            (n_upper, n_lower + 1)
        } else {
            (n_upper, n_lower)
        }
    });
    
    n_upper > n_lower
}
```

will output:

```
warning: default numeric fallback might occur
 --> src/lib.rs:4:46
  |
4 |     let (n_upper, n_lower) = s.chars().fold((0, 0), |(n_upper, n_lower), c| {
  |                                              ^ help: consider adding suffix: `0_i32`
  |
note: the lint level is defined here
 --> src/lib.rs:1:8
  |
1 | #[warn(clippy::default_numeric_fallback)]
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#default_numeric_fallback

warning: default numeric fallback might occur
 --> src/lib.rs:4:49
  |
4 |     let (n_upper, n_lower) = s.chars().fold((0, 0), |(n_upper, n_lower), c| {
  |                                                 ^ help: consider adding suffix: `0_i32`
  |
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#default_numeric_fallback

warning: default numeric fallback might occur
 --> src/lib.rs:6:24
  |
6 |             (n_upper + 1, n_lower)
  |                        ^ help: consider adding suffix: `1_i32`
  |
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#default_numeric_fallback

warning: default numeric fallback might occur
 --> src/lib.rs:8:33
  |
8 |             (n_upper, n_lower + 1)
  |                                 ^ help: consider adding suffix: `1_i32`
  |
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#default_numeric_fallback
```

Unfortunately the lint is not warn for now but only in pedantic list. And it's strange to suggest `i32` as default. For example, this code sample should use `usize`.

Source: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/6064